# Empty array returned

Tags: java, graph

```
static ArrayList<Integer> furthestAirport(int departingAirport) {
        int max = 2, currentSize = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int endKey : stationKeys) {
            if (departingAirport != endKey) {
                HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> tempHash = g.shortestPaths(departingAirport, endKey);
                if (!tempHash.isEmpty()) {
                    for (ArrayList temp : tempHash) {
                        currentSize = temp.size();
                        if (max <= currentSize) {
                            max = currentSize;
                            if (!tempList.contains(endKey))
                                tempList.add(endKey);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int endKey : tempList) {
            if (departingAirport != endKey) {
                HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> tempHash = g.shortestPaths(departingAirport, endKey);
                if (!tempHash.isEmpty()) {
                    for (ArrayList temp : tempHash) {
                        currentSize = temp.size();
                        if (max == currentSize) {
                            if (!result.contains(endKey))
                                result.add(endKey);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Hi, Can someone help me find whats wrong with my method. Is is designed to find the furthest distance from an airport(vertice).

It is returning an empty array.
I appreciate if someone could help me as I am alone.

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: Your code will return empty list if the longest path has not more than 2 segments, because you have 'max = 2' at the start.

Comment: It's hard to tell what might go wrong with all that nesting which seems overly complicated anyway. Why are you iterating twice? Unless I missed something I'd say that one iteration should be enough even with unsorted lists. If you encounter a new max you clear the result list and add the current element to the list otherwise you add it if the current element's distance is equal to the current max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll expand on my comment a little and add some code to make it clearer:

```
static List<Integer> furthestAirport(int departingAirport) { //(1)
    int max = 2;
    Set<Integer> result = new LinkedHashSet<>(); //(2)

    for (int endKey : stationKeys) {
        if (departingAirport != endKey) {  
            //(!!)
            Set<List<Integer>> tempHash = g.shortestPaths(departingAirport, endKey); //(1)
            if (!tempHash.isEmpty()) { // should that ever happen?
                for (List<Integer> tempList : tempHash) {

                    if( tempList.size() > max ) { //(3)
                       result.clear();
                       result.add(endKey); 
                    } else if( tempList.size() == max ) { //(4)
                       result.add(endKey); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(result);
}
```

Notes:

- (1): use interfaces for variables to be able to change the implementation used
- (2): using LinkedHashSet allows to keep the order of insertion and let the collection handle duplicates (they won't be added)
- (3): if the current `tempList`is larger than the current max size remove anything that might have been collected so far because that can only be shorter. Then add the current `endKey` because it represents that farthest airport "so far".
- (4): if the current `tempList` is as long as the current max size then just add another `endKey` (this would also handle any "first" path of length 2)
- (!!): this could contain errors which might result in no path of at least length 2 being found